# Is this JSON structure suitable for a stacked bar chart using d3.js?

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I need to create a stacked bar chart plus line graph. I'm thinking d3.js is the tool for the job, but I'm having problems binding my data. Is the following JSON formatted in a way that will work for the stack method?

```
{
"response": {
    "qtime": 11,
    "params": {
        "id": "jb8wp1rw41v",
        "format": "json"
    }
},
"series": {
    "twitter": [{
        "date": "2013-08-20",
        "value": 3
    }, {
        "date": "2013-08-21",
        "value": 1
    }, {
        "date": "2013-08-22",
        "value": 4
    }, {
        "date": "2013-08-23",
        "value": 1
    }, {
        "date": "2013-08-24",
        "value": 5
    }, {
        "date": "2013-08-25",
        "value": 9
    }, {
        "date": "2013-08-26",
        "value": 2
    }, {
        "date": "2013-08-27",
        "value": 6
    }, {
        "date": "2013-08-28",
        "value": 5
    }, {
        "date": "2013-08-29",
        "value": 3
    }, {
        "date": "2013-08-30",
        "value": 5
    }, {
        "date": "2013-08-31",
        "value": 8
    }, {
        "date": "2013-09-01",
        "value": 9
    }, {
        "date": "2013-09-02",
        "value": 7
    }],
    "facebook": [{
        "date": "2013-08-20",
        "value": 0
    }, {
        "date": "2013-08-21",
        "value": 1
    }, {
        "date": "2013-08-22",
        "value": 3
    }, {
        "date": "2013-08-23",
        "value": 6
    }, {
        "date": "2013-08-24",
        "value": 10
    }, {
        "date": "2013-08-25",
        "value": 21
    }, {
        "date": "2013-08-26",
        "value": 28
    }, {
        "date": "2013-08-27",
        "value": 21
    }, {
        "date": "2013-08-28",
        "value": 10
    }, {
        "date": "2013-08-29",
        "value": 6
    }, {
        "date": "2013-08-30",
        "value": 0
    }, {
        "date": "2013-08-31",
        "value": 15
    }, {
        "date": "2013-09-01",
        "value": 21
    }, {
        "date": "2013-09-02",
        "value": 1
    }],
    "email": [{
        "date": "2013-08-20",
        "value": 0
    }, {
        "date": "2013-08-21",
        "value": 1
    }, {
        "date": "2013-08-22",
        "value": 1
    }, {
        "date": "2013-08-23",
        "value": 2
    }, {
        "date": "2013-08-24",
        "value": 3
    }, {
        "date": "2013-08-25",
        "value": 5
    }, {
        "date": "2013-08-26",
        "value": 8
    }, {
        "date": "2013-08-27",
        "value": 13
    }, {
        "date": "2013-08-28",
        "value": 5
    }, {
        "date": "2013-08-29",
        "value": 8
    }, {
        "date": "2013-08-30",
        "value": 1
    }, {
        "date": "2013-08-31",
        "value": 1
    }, {
        "date": "2013-09-01",
        "value": 2
    }, {
        "date": "2013-09-02",
        "value": 13
    }],
    "amazon_rank": [{
        "date": "2013-08-20",
        "value": 1001
    }, {
        "date": "2013-08-21",
        "value": 2312
    }, {
        "date": "2013-08-22",
        "value": 2300
    }, {
        "date": "2013-08-23",
        "value": 5179
    }, {
        "date": "2013-08-24",
        "value": 5112
    }, {
        "date": "2013-08-25",
        "value": 2305
    }, {
        "date": "2013-08-26",
        "value": 1902
    }, {
        "date": "2013-08-27",
        "value": 1221
    }, {
        "date": "2013-08-28",
        "value": 1010
    }, {
        "date": "2013-08-29",
        "value": 2588
    }, {
        "date": "2013-08-30",
        "value": 4093
    }, {
        "date": "2013-08-31",
        "value": 4432
    }, {
        "date": "2013-09-01",
        "value": 5002
    }, {
        "date": "2013-09-02",
        "value": 3902
    }],
    "pinterest": [{
        "date": "2013-08-20",
        "value": 17
    }, {
        "date": "2013-08-21",
        "value": 23
    }, {
        "date": "2013-08-22",
        "value": 11
    }, {
        "date": "2013-08-23",
        "value": 13
    }, {
        "date": "2013-08-24",
        "value": 19
    }, {
        "date": "2013-08-25",
        "value": 5
    }, {
        "date": "2013-08-26",
        "value": 17
    }, {
        "date": "2013-08-27",
        "value": 11
    }, {
        "date": "2013-08-28",
        "value": 2
    }, {
        "date": "2013-08-29",
        "value": 3
    }, {
        "date": "2013-08-30",
        "value": 5
    }, {
        "date": "2013-08-31",
        "value": 7
    }, {
        "date": "2013-09-01",
        "value": 19
    }, {
        "date": "2013-09-02",
        "value": 0
    }]
}
```

}

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to wrangle the data a little bit to get in a format that d3 likes, but there are built in functions to do all the work for you:

```
var companies = d3.layout.stack()(d3.values(json.series))
```

will give you a data structure similar to `causes` in the stacked [bar chart example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1134768).

Basically, [d3.values](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Arrays#wiki-d3_values) is taking your object with several arrays and turning in into an array of arrays. [d3.layout.stack](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Stack-Layout) takes that two dimensional array, re structures it a a little bit and adds convenience functions that make it much simpler create a stacked bar chart.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to *not* use JSON at all since it is not streamable. Indeed, charts are often representing a big amount of datas and it is recommended to load their content progressively with the help of the XHR progress event.

Since most of the charts are tabular datas, i assume CSV is the better format for that purpose. If you still want be able to manage trees like with JSON, take a look at VarStream https://github.com/nfroidure/VarStream.

Here is an example of loading charts with a streamable format versus with JSON : http://server.elitwork.com/experiments/chartstream/index.html

The badest is your connection, the more you see how usefull is XHR Streaming.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm only looking at an MVP chart at the moment and just need to know if this JSON is formatted in a way that will work with d3's stacking.

I'll be sure to show your answer to the developers for future reference :)

Comment: JSON is fine for this chart. There really isn't that much raw data being sent and with values updating once a day, I don't think steaming adds anything. There are already enough random bits of knowledge required to create stuff with d3; I don't think suggesting learning a new file format is super helpful for people starting out.